# ¿Por qué ocurre el error: TypeError: Can only call FormData.append on instances of FormData?

Tags: jquery, ajax, formdata

Estaba respondiendo a una pregunta en la que se trataba de enviar solamente parte de un formulario al servidor vía Ajax, y enviar también un archivo.

Crée un objeto `FormData` al cual le agregué los datos de la parte del formulario que interesaba y el archivo.

Pero el código me estaba dando el error:

> TypeError: Can only call FormData.append on instances of FormData

El problema se resolvió al agregar en la parte de Ajax lo siguiente:

```
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
```

Cuando el código fallaba yo no le había puesto el parámetro `processData`, y en el `contentType` tenía `multipart/form-data;`, (lo cual era lo lógico para mi).

Lo que no entiendo es por qué el código fallaba y daba ese error si realmente lo que estaba enviando era un formulario `multipart`.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe ese comportamiento de Ajax y si hay una mejor manera de hacerlo?

Este es el código, el cual funciona, lo que no entiendo es por qué hay que poner esos dos atributos como `false`.

```
$( function() { 

  $('#btnSend').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var partialData = $(this).closest('fieldset').serialize();
    var csvFile=$('#csvInput')[0].files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data',partialData); 
    formData.append('file', csvFile);

    var request = $.ajax
        ({
            url: 'action.php',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        request.done(function( msg )
        {
            console.log("hecho: "+msg);
        });

        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus )
        {
            alert( "Hubo un error: " + textStatus );
        });

  });    

});
```

Comment: Tanto leyendo la [documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) como así a primeras, pareciera ser tema de *qué* estás enviando en tu form... Por ejemplo, archivos? (lo pregunto, porque como elegiste el `multipart/form-data`, cuando hay otros más simples, especialmente si *no* vas a enviar archivos :O )...

Comment: @quinqui lo dije en la introducción de la pregunta: *Estaba respondiendo a una pregunta en la que se trataba de enviar solamente parte de un formulario al servidor vía Ajax, **y enviar también un archivo.*** Por eso recurrí a `multipart` :)

Comment: Uh, mi error. Tienes razón -_-

Comment: Bueno, precisamente en la documentación mencionan que si no quieres mandar datos que sean tratados como objetos de formulario, mejor elegir dar `false` a la opción `processData`, y ya que estás enviando un CSV, que es texto plano, tal vez vaya por ahí la cosa... Oo